# Large heap size - phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, memory-management, heap-memory

While debugging HTML based android apps packaged with phonegap/Cordova, I have seen large heap size in logcat.

Can any one explain me what could be the issue here?

How can this be minimized or resolved?